# SQL Multipart identifier error when attempting to filter using a field from a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok, I'm not very good with SQL, so I don't know how to solve this one. I have this query:

```
DECLARE @supplyPointIds TABLE
                        (
                            id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                        )
INSERT INTO @supplyPointIds (id)
VALUES ('1DC9A405-4EC5-4379-BB2C-110973A9936B'),
       ('65745684-7D00-4D8A-9735-2C5BA29852B0')
SELECT R.Id AS LastReadingId, R.SupplyPointInstallationId
FROM Reading R
WHERE R.SupplyPointInstallationId IN (SELECT id FROM @supplyPointIds)
ORDER BY R.SupplyPointInstallationId, R.LastDate DESC
```

And it produces this:

[image]

But what I want to get is this only:

[image]

So, I wrote this query:

```
DECLARE @supplyPointIds TABLE
                        (
                            id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                        )
INSERT INTO @supplyPointIds (id)
VALUES ('1DC9A405-4EC5-4379-BB2C-110973A9936B'),
       ('65745684-7D00-4D8A-9735-2C5BA29852B0')
SELECT ReadingId.Id AS LastReadingId, R.SupplyPointInstallationId
FROM Reading R,
     (SELECT TOP 1 RID.Id
      FROM Reading RID
      WHERE RID.SupplyPointInstallationId = R.SupplyPointInstallationId
      ORDER BY RID.LastDate) AS ReadingId -- Only the most recent reading
WHERE R.SupplyPointInstallationId IN (SELECT id FROM @supplyPointIds)
ORDER BY R.SupplyPointInstallationId DESC
```

But, unfortunately, I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "R.SupplyPointInstallationId" could not be
> bound.

How can I do to get only those two records I want?

Comment: Your subquery, doesn't have access to outer table `R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to join the two tables and use the row_number function as the following:

```
SELECT R.Id AS LastReadingId, R.SupplyPointInstallationId
FROM 
  (
    SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SupplyPointInstallationId ORDER BY LastDate DESC) rn
    FROM Reading
  ) R JOIN @supplyPointIds S
ON S.id = R.SupplyPointInstallationId
WHERE R.rn = 1
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9xghhHhf)

This can be also written as:

```
SELECT LastReadingId, SupplyPointInstallationId
  From
(
  SELECT R.Id AS LastReadingId, R.SupplyPointInstallationId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.SupplyPointInstallationId ORDER BY R.LastDate DESC) rn
  FROM Reading R JOIN @supplyPointIds S
  ON S.id = R.SupplyPointInstallationId
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Although I think the compiler is capable of pushing it through automatically, makes sense to also push the join into the subquery, probably better performance.